# Macro that checks if cell has Circular reference

Tags: excel, vba, circular-reference

Made a macro that look if cell is part of a circular reference chain.

But is it also possible to make the macro show the arrows of the circualar reference chain?

```
Sub Circ_ref()

Set Start = Range("B2")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set c = Start.DirectDependents
    propertyExists = (Err = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

If propertyExists = False Then Exit Sub

Dim counter As Integer

counter = 0
opnieuw:

For Each c_dep In c

    'Debug.Print c.Address & "-------"

        Debug.Print c_dep.Address & c_dep.Formula
        Debug.Print c.Count

        If c_dep.Address = Start.Address Then
            MsgBox c_dep.Address & "   CIRCLE"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    If counter = c.Count - 1 Then
        counter = 0
        Set c = c.DirectDependents
        Debug.Print c.Address & "    Volgende cell"
        GoTo opnieuw
    Else
        counter = counter + 1
    End If

Next c_dep

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you refering to the [`Range.ShowDependents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.showdependents) method?

Comment: Yes, but I only want to show the circular reference chain, not all the arrows to all the other referenced cells that are not part of the circular reference.